# Trying to convert a nested loop with two sequences into a lambda

Tags: python, lambda

i've got this function that checks all the words in the 1st sequence,
if they are ending with one of the words in the 2nd sequence, remove that end substring.

I'm trying to achieve all that in one simple lambda function that is supposed to go into a pipeline processing, and can't find a way to do it.

I'll be grateful if you could help me with this:

```
str_test = ("Thiship is a test string testing slowly i'm helpless")
stem_rules = ('less', 'ship', 'ing', 'es', 'ly','s')

str_test2 = str_test.split()

for i in str_test2:
    for j in stem_rules:
        if(i.endswith(j)):
            str_test2[str_test2.index(i)] = i[:-len(j)]
            break
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a lambda? There is no difference between a lambda and a regular function from the point of view of any routine you might call.

Comment: @kindall i'm doing a project which has to be made with only lambdas, i know it's making it a lot harder but it has to be that way.

Comment: Yeah, no. Fire that boss immediately.

Comment: @argamanza It doesn't make it much harder, rather more silly.

Comment: Yeah i know and it's a pain in the a**, i'm trying to do it for a while now and i can't find out how...

Comment: @argamanza still confused as to why it "has to be that way." If it's an executive decision, then it's time to find new employment. If it's a software dependency, then you're probably wrong and it DOESN'T have to be that way.

Comment: It's probably a school project where he has to practice lambda or something.

Comment: @Gab I think you're right. And I think what his teacher wants to see is some extremely golfed code with reduce\lambda. A terrible way to teach lambdas if you ask me.

Comment: @Rusty that's exactly the case, not lambdas though, it's pipeline processing with no auxiliary functions.

Comment: @argamanza yeah, you should mention such things beforehand, because people here are trying to help you solve the problem the RIGHT way, but  what you are asking is the WRONG way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a one-liner that activates a (simple?) lambda that does it.

```
(lambda words, rules: sum([[word[:-len(rule)]] if word.endswith(rule) else [] for word in words for rule in rules], []))(str_test.split(), stem_rules)
```

It's not clear how it's working, and it's not good practice to do it.

What it generally does is create a list with a single string out of matches, or an empty list out of misses, and then aggregates everything to single list, containing only the matches.

Currently it will output on **every** match, and not just longest match or anything like that, but once you figure out how it's working, maybe you can select the shortest match from the list of matches for each word in the input.

May god be with you.

Comment: This is hilarious, a proper answer for a bad question.

Comment: @Rusty let's be fair: it's actually a very GOOD question, it's just a bad PREMISE. The thing that OP has to do (for whatever reason) *must not be done*. However OP has expressed it very clearly and obviously has some working knowledge of the subject.

Comment: @AdamSmith not really an answer then, "I'm trying to achieve all that in one simple lambda"... Doesn't look very simple :).

Comment: @Rusty sorry you feel that way, i wasn't trying to ask a good or bad question, only tried to find a solution for a question i had no choice but asking.

Comment: It's really is a nice solution but i can't find a way to go over ALL the rules in the stem_rules sequence.
Looks like i'll have to use some kind of loop but still, can't find out how..

Comment: This goes over all the rules, with no exceptions. I think you want some exceptions... That's why a `lambda` would be very **not** intuitive in a smarter implementation (split to cases).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is toss your `i.endswith(j) for j in stem_rules` out and make it a regex that matches and captures the prefix string and matches (but doesn't capture) any suffix

```
import re

match_end = re.compile("(.*?)(?:" + "|".join(".*?" + stem + "$" for stem in stem_rules) + ")")
# This is the same as:

re.compile(r"""
    (.*?)          # Capturing group matching the prefix
    (?:            # Begins a non-capturing group...
        stem1$|
        stem2$|
        stem3$     # ...which matches an alternation of the stems, asserting end of string
    )              # ends the non-capturing group""", re.X)
```

Then you can use that regex to sub each item in the list.

```
f = lambda word: match_end.sub(r"\1", word)
```

Use that wrapped in a list comprehension and you should have your result

```
words = [f(word) for word in str_test.split()]
# or map(f, str_test.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert you current code into a single lambda, each step in the pipeline needs to behave in a very functional manner: receive some data, and then emit some data. You need to avoid anything that deviates from that paradigm -- in particular, the use of things like `break`. Here's one way to rewrite the steps in that manner:

```
text   = ("Thiship is a test string testing slowly i'm helpless")
stems  = ('less', 'ship', 'ing', 'es', 'ly','s')

# The steps:
#   - get words from the text
#   - pair each word with its matching stems
#   - create a list of cleaned words (stems removed)
#   - make the new text
words  = text.split()
wstems = [ (w, [s for s in stems if w.endswith(s)]) for w in words ]
cwords = [ w[0:-len(ss[0])] if ss else w for w, ss in wstems ]
text2  = ' '.join(cwords)
print text2
```

With those parts in hands, a single lambda can be created using ordinary substitution. Here's the monstrosity:

```
f = lambda txt: [
    w[0:-len(ss[0])] if ss else w
    for w, ss in [ (w, [s for s in stems if w.endswith(s)]) for w in txt.split() ]
]
text3 = ' '.join(f(text))
print text3
```

I wasn't sure whether you want the lambda to return the new words or the new text -- adjust as needed.